# I am having trouble making an input text box that goes through a function and outputs test to an output textbox with Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

**im new to Python3.6.2**
So I want a program that takes an input (Via text box from tkinter) and outputs a word in my custom "language"

with this function

```
def Mescre(n):
  Words = (n)
  Mes = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ektnopzcamjqwyuxsbfdiglhrv')
  print(Words.translate(Mes))
```

and here's what i want the window to look like

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

Mescre = Label(root,  text="Input:")
English = Label(root , text="Output:")

label1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
label2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)

entry1.grid = (row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid = (row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

if "hello" was in the Input text box, i want the output to be "coqqu" in the Output text box.

Comment: And what exactly is your issue? Where does your solution deviate from your expectations? What have you tried to solve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: yes i was stuck, the Tkinter stuff is new to me.

Comment: The question is not if you are stuck, but where. People here are generally very kind and helpful, but you have to show some effort on your own.

Comment: updated my post, or at least that's what I felt you hinted me to do.

Comment: @Lumine Stack Overflow is not a free programming service, the people who answer your questions on here are doing so of their own free will in their own free time. We are here to help you through specific programming issues and saying to someone "I am stuck" will not help you to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Lumine No, I want you to realise that we are people who are trying to help you and you cannot come on here making demands and not  helping us to help you. Also rude and snarky comments are against site policy, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my example below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.sv = StringVar()
        self.Mes = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ektnopzcamjqwyuxsbfdiglhrv')
        self.entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.sv)
        self.label = Label(self.root)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.label.pack()
        self.sv.trace("w", self.callback)
    def callback(self, *args):
        self.label.configure({"text": self.entry.get().translate(self.Mes)})

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here we define a `StringVar()` to be the value of the attribute `textvariable` for the `Entry` widget.

We then assign a `callback` to a `trace()` on the variable so that whenever the variable is updated (When someone types in the `Entry`) we call `callback()`.

Within `callback()` we use `configure()` on the `Label` widget in order to set the text to equal the post translation version of the value of the `Entry` widget.

This creates a "live updating" translation effect.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
def Mescre():
  val = textfield.get()
  Words = (val)
  Mes = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ektnopzcamjqwyuxsbfdiglhrv')
  print(Words.translate(Mes))

textfield = tk.Entry(root)
textfield.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, command=Mescre, text='Push')
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Push button to translate text to function]

---

**Updated**:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
def Mescre():
  val = textfield.get()
  Words = (val)
  Mes = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ektnopzcamjqwyuxsbfdiglhrv')
  translation = Words.translate(Mes)
  #print(translation)
  outputfield.delete(0, tk.END)
  outputfield.insert(0, translation)


textfield = tk.Entry(root)
textfield.pack()
outputfield = tk.Entry(root)
outputfield.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, command=Mescre, text='Push')
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but is there a way to print to a separate text box inside the window or in this case root

Comment: something like

`root = Tk()

Mescre = Label(root,  text="Input:")
English = Label(root , text="Output:")

label1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
label2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)

entry1.grid = (row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid = (row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()`

Comment: I would suggest struggling with the documentation and working through simple examples. How do you delete content from an entry widget? How do you insert content into an entry widget? How do you make an entry widget? Etc.